# Error when trying to store function result to a variable using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, function, parsing, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm trying to create a stored procedure or a trigger in which it will store the function result inside a variable and insert it to a table.

Here's my function which parse raw data

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_Parserstring] 
    (@StringInput VARCHAR(max))
 RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ([String] VARCHAR(max))
 AS
 BEGIN
      DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(max)

      WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
      BEGIN
         SET @String = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                            ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                            LEN(@StringInput)))
         SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                      ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @StringInput), 0),
                                      LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

         INSERT INTO @OutputTable ([String])
         VALUES (@String)
      END

      RETURN
 END
```

After it parses the raw data I will call the results using the stored procedure which stores the result inside a variable

Here's the stored procedure I'm trying to do

Kindly advice if wrong or not

```
declare @str2 varchar(max)
declare @account varchar(max)
declare @GPS varchar(max)

set @str2  = (SELECT TOP 1 smsmsg FROM GPRSIN)

set @account = (SELECT TOP 2 * 
                FROM 
                   (SELECT 
                       String, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY String desc) AS Rownumber
                    FROM [dbo].[ufn_Parserstring] ( replace(@str2,';',','))) results
                WHERE results.Rownumber = 2)

set @GPS = (SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM 
                (SELECT 
                     String, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY String desc) AS Rownumber
                FROM [dbo].[ufn_Parserstring] (replace(@str2,';',','))) results
            WHERE results.Rownumber = 1)
```

Whenever I try running this I get this error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

If you need the flow then here's the flow

```
351856040489593
241111
 1R
 141119040115
 A
 1422.1425N
12103.1746E
0.0
151
1.8
01000006
```

rawdata -> parse by the function parser which give a result like the one above. -> the SP im trying to do will store the query result to variable -> insert the value of variables to a certain table (for example tblblablabla)

Kindly help me guys.

Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to populate a variable by selecting the top two results from the subquery. The problem lies in the statement `set @account = (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM`

Comment: specifically the use of * is what is causing the error

Comment: What should I do now? Thanks.